# Parsing unclosed `}` tags

Tags: php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1X5q.png)

I want to use html code between `foreach`, but I get this error about not closing the tag (`}`)

> error Message :
> ( ! ) Parse error: Unclosed '{' on line 26 in D:\xampp\htdocs\php\php_lernen\myphp\databasepdo.php on line 52

does anyone maybe know about this error message? Here is the Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>user name</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>email</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $servername = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'test';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
        $results = $conn->query($sql);
        foreach ($results as $results) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $results['id'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results['username'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results['name'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results['mail'] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
    ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using `<?php` for the opening tag instead of  `<?`

Comment: I did it but it's the same error 
( ! ) Parse error: Unclosed '{' on line 28 in D:\xampp\htdocs\php\php_lernen\myphp\databasepdo.php on line 43

Comment: Could not reproduce after replacing `<?` with `<?php` in line 36 (at the end of foreach): https://ideone.com/cEJsfC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the php tag on line 36. Try this:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
    $results = $conn->query($sql);
    foreach ($results as $results) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $results['id'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $results['username'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $results['name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $results['mail'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php // <------ Missing php tag here
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a ';' right after you come back into your php code, the <? before your closing bracket }.

When you exit your php to insert some html in that particular case or loop iteration, it is still a 'line' of code as far as your PHP goes and needs to be ended appropriately, thus ';'. Here is that portion of code fixed:

```
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
        $results = $conn->query($sql);
        foreach ($results as $results) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $results['id'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results['username'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results['name'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results['mail'] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?; # <---- this ; here
        }
```

You also want to stick with <?php in these cases as I found in my own personal php that not including the entire opening tag caused my script to become unaware of the start and stop of my php code sections.

Comment: That semicolon is absolutely unnecessary. And not just that, it will probably cause a different syntax error.

Comment: In my experience that is not true. Without the semicolon my web server could not resolve the closing bracket to my else statement to its opening bracket. If I remove the semicolon right now and reload my webserver the page will break. And my page is set up as it is above  except mine is in a IF-Else statement instead of foreach. Could be version dependent? I'm using PHP 7.4.12 on an Apache webserver. I wracked my brain for a long while trying to resolve this problem and the semicolon worked for me.

Comment: I don't know the setup of your script or what code you're dealing with, but here it is only going to do damage. Maybe if you shared your code we could identify the how and why.